# Why is the span element rendered by the Text component from the Grommet library, able to get margin-top?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, grommet

Normally spans should not get any margin-top, so what gives? Also, for some reason, if I place a Text instance inside a form element, then it no longer gets the margin-top as it normally should be the case?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'grommet';
import SandboxComponent from './SandboxComponent';

export default () => (
  <SandboxComponent>
    <Text margin={{top: '10px'}}>Ricky town, population... Ricky</Text>
  </SandboxComponent>
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/grommet/grommet-sandbox?initialpath=text&module=%2Fsrc%2FText.js

Comment: It's rendered out as `<span>` but has css property of `display: block`, thats why you can apply margin top to the `<Text>` component.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to have a display property. Even if you add 'display: inline' in there, it still gets the margin-top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<SandboxComponent>` is set to `display: flex` and that's why you can set margin on `<Text>` even if it's inline by default. If you would remove `<SandboxComponent>` component and output just `<Text>` it will be just inline element.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'grommet';

export default () => (
  <Text margin={{top: '10px'}}>Ricky town, population... Ricky</Text>
);
```

Try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/grommet-sandbox-n8mww

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know a flex box's children can get margin-top even if that child is a span element.